# Should I put tables in a standalone environment?

Tags: tables, compiling, standalone

In the past, to speed up compilation when writing TikZ I would put the TikZ code into a standalone document to compile it separately. This way, it wasn't recompiling every time I compiled the main LaTeX document. Should I do the same for Tables? I have a feeling that having a lot of tables will slow down compilation, so I'm thinking of putting each table in its own standalone document, and then compiling them separately. Is there any point in doing this?

Comment: tables aren't appreciably slower than paragraphs compared with the the overhead of reading extra files from the filesystem I doubt it makes much difference. (table packages that do multiple trial runs may possibly be slower but still doubt the extra complication is worth it) you can always try it and time the runs.